# Live site no longer reflecting what is in the CPanel

Tags: html, dns, web, cpanel, web-hosting

Yesterday I changed the background of my website, and added an images folder with images inside it (Ex. /images/background.jpg), and the changes were showing on the site(quicosolutions.com). The changes today are no longer showing on the site, but all the changes and files are still present in cPanel.

Maybe related, I changed my nameservers to cloudflare yesterday so I could get an SSL on my site.

Comment: Is it possible you are looking at a cached version of your site?

Comment: I don't think so, I was repeatedly refreshing my browser yesterday with it up and was able to go to those image url paths.